# Como a função int() lida com o caractere \n?

Tags: python, string, int, python-internals

Criei uma lista:

```
usuarios = ['123\n','123\n4']
```

Tentei transformar o índice 0 em inteiro usando o `int()`

```
int(usuarios[0])
```

Resultado:

```
123
```

Mas quando tentei fazer o mesmo com o índice 1:

```
int(usuarios[1])
```

resultado:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '123\n4'

Gostaria se possível de saber todas as regras do `int()`, pois não as encontro ao menos em português.

Comment: Quando tiver dúvias desse tipo, eu sugiro usar o modo interativo do Python e fazer algumas tentativas livres - e ver as respostas. Na verdade, sugiro sempre mante rum promprt interativo aberto e testar quase tudo lá - o autocomplete da IDE dimuni a necessiade de algumas coisas de mexer "de verdade" e "ao vivo" no código - mas não é nem de longe didático igual.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A regra é simples, precisa ser uma *string* com um valor numérico inteiro válido, ou seja, não possuir caracteres que atrapalhem o correto entendimento do seu valor, nem mesmo ponto decimal. Alguns poucos caracteres são aceitos após os números por serem considerados neutros (em geral são o espaço em branco, tabulação, quebras de linha etc.).

Quando é identificado que o número pode ser interpretado de alguma forma diferente, ocorrerá uma exceção `ValueError`.

Estes exemplos funcionam:

```
print(int('12\n'))
print(int('\n123'))
print(int('1234 '))
print(int(' 1235'))
```

Estes não:

```
print(int('1236c'))
print(int('a1237'))
print(int('123 8'))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/TnTxVJ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lpzqjwpw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Typing/ConvertingToInt.py).

Answer (score 9):

Conforme a [documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#int):

> **class int([x])**
>
> [...] *If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string, bytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in radix base. Optionally, the literal can be preceded by + or - (with no space in between) **and surrounded by whitespace**.*

Conforme trecho em destaque, o valor do parâmetro pode estar **cercado** de espaços em branco. Para efeitos práticos, será realizado um *trim* na *string* antes de convertê-la para inteiro, ignorando, assim, espaços em branco do início e do final.

## TL;DR

**As informações abaixo são baseadas na implementação oficial do Python, conhecida como CPython.**

Para confirmar essa informação, você pode analisar a [implementação do Python em C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b509d52083e156f97d6bd36f2f894a052e960f03/Objects/longobject.c#L2213):

```c
/* Parses an int from a bytestring. Leading and trailing whitespace will be
 * ignored.
 *
 * If successful, a PyLong object will be returned and 'pend' will be pointing
 * to the first unused byte unless it's NULL.
 *
 * If unsuccessful, NULL will be returned.
 */
PyObject *
PyLong_FromString(const char *str, char **pend, int base);
```

O valor que você passa como parâmetro em `int` será o ponteiro `*s`. Ao analisar o corpo da função, verá que [logo no início](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b509d52083e156f97d6bd36f2f894a052e960f03/Objects/longobject.c#L2226) (linha 2226) há:

```c
while (*str != '\0' && Py_ISSPACE(Py_CHARMASK(*str))) {
    str++;
}
```

Isto é, percorre a *string* e se for um espaço em branco incrementa o ponteiro, fazendo com que o caractere seja ignorado nos passos posteriores. Será considerado espaço em branco todo e qualquer caractere que `Py_ISSPACE` retornar verdadeiro.

```c
#define Py_ISSPACE(c)  (_Py_ctype_table[Py_CHARMASK(c)] & PY_CTF_SPACE)

// pyctype.c

PY_CTF_SPACE, /* 0x9 '\t' */
PY_CTF_SPACE, /* 0xa '\n' */
PY_CTF_SPACE, /* 0xb '\v' */
PY_CTF_SPACE, /* 0xc '\f' */
PY_CTF_SPACE, /* 0xd '\r' */
```

Ou seja, os caracteres `\t`, `\n`, `\v`, `\f` e `\r` serão desconsiderados na *string*.

```
>>> int('\t1')
1
>>> int('\n2')
2
>>> int('\v3')
3
>>> int('\f4')
4
>>> int('\r5')
5
```

Continuando a análise do corpo da função, [vemos o trecho](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b509d52083e156f97d6bd36f2f894a052e960f03/Objects/longobject.c#L2399) (linha 2399):

```
scan = str;

# ...

while (_PyLong_DigitValue[Py_CHARMASK(*scan)] < base || *scan == '_') {
    # ...
}
```

Ele atribui o ponteiro de entrada `str` para `scan` e o percorre enquanto o caractere for um dígito válido, isto é, menor do que a base informada, ou o caractere `_`. Qualquer caractere que não satisfaz essas condições fará com que seja executado `goto onError`, finalizando a função com erro. Portanto, dentro do número será permitido o caractere `_` apenas, mas qualquer outro caractere, incluindo os espaços em branco, resultarão em erro.

```
>>> int('1_000')
1000
>>> int('1\n000')
...
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1\n000'
```

Finalmente, continuando a análise do copo da função, [vemos novamente](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b509d52083e156f97d6bd36f2f894a052e960f03/Objects/longobject.c#L2535) (linha 2535):

```c
while (*str && Py_ISSPACE(Py_CHARMASK(*str))) {
    str++;
}

if (*str != '\0') {
    goto onError;
}
```

De forma semelhante ao anterior, para ignorar os espaços em branco do início da *string*, é percorrido o ponteiro ignorando os espaços em branco do final. A condição de terminar em `\0` garante que a *string* termine com espaços em branco e não com outros caracteres.

Resumindo,

- Qualquer espaço em branco do início será ignorado (`' '`, `'\t'`, `'\n'`, `'\v'`, `'\f'`, `'\r'`);
- Durante a *string*, qualquer caractere que não seja dígito ou `_` dará erro;
- Qualquer espaço em branco do final será ignorado;
- Qualquer caractere que não seja dígito ou `_` dará erro, exceto casos supracitados (espaços do início e fim);

Comment: Incrível resposta! No seu resumo final, faltou listar que "qualquer outro caractere no fim da string dará erro."

Comment: @MárioFeroldi bem colocado, obrigado.